# Why is numpy.round giving the incorrect output?

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

[image]

Since when does 8.5 round to 8.0? I thought maybe it just round 0.5 down, but 7.5 also round to 8.0? Is numpy broken or am I missing something...

I tried a few numbers, it's also broken for 0.5 giving 0.0 instead of 1.0. Any clue what's going on?

Comment: I believe it is using the "round half even" algorithm.  It rounds exactly .5 to the nearest even number instead of always rounding up to be more fair.

Comment: @MarkTolonen [is correct.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.round.html) `Notes:
For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc.`

Comment: Why are you not reading the documentation?

Comment: For the same reason that the built-in `round` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

From the built-in Python help:

```
import numpy as np
help(np.round)
```

```
   ...
   Notes
    -----
    For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy
    rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0,
    -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc.
   ...
```

For further reading, the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module describes a number of [rounding modes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes), including the [`ROUND_HALF_EVEN`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN) used by `numpy`.